# Does WPF Textbox respect Unicode BIDI controls like LRI/RLI?

Tags: wpf, textbox, bidi

I need to display English + Hebrew text mixed in a text box. I embed each language with the appropriate RLI/LRI/PDI controls but it seems that it doesn't make any difference. Depending on the content, things end up out of order, like if the BIDI controls are being ignored.
To check that my BIDI controls are placed correctly, I take the same text displayed in the textbox  and put it in Clipboard. Pasting it to notepad or word displays the text in the expected order while on the textbox it isn't.

Can someone confirm if WPF textbox should respect these Unicode BIDI controls?
Am I missing any special setting on the textbox so it takes it into consideration?

Comment: It's just a text box.  One box. You put your text in it.  If you want just a special character like an o with an ummlaut, that can work. But you seem to be expecting ms word inside a textbox. That ain't gonna work. You could maybe do something with a richtextbox.

Comment: I don't agree. It is a text box displaying a unicode string. It should work. Nothing to do with formatting or like you say "ms word", just the order where the chars are displayed. Notepad does it correctly, why can't the text box do it?